# referencing custom xsd causes intellisense to only work above schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Here is the scenario

1. Create XSD schema called foo.xsd in C:\Users\Win7Guru\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\foo.xsd
2. Create new xml file
3. Add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?` at the top of the xml document
4. Add a schema tag `<xs:schema xmlns="C:\Users\Win7Guru\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\foo.xsd"` and a closing tag `</xs:schema>`
5. Type `<` and wait for intellisense to appear, but all that shows is the default selections

---

1. `-->`
2. `<![CDATA[]]>`
3. `?`

---

Using Visual Studio 2012 RTM

> When I try step 5 above the schema, such as
>
> > `1. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
> >
> > `2.  <------`
> >
> > `3. <xs:schema xmlns="C:\Users\Win7Guru\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\foo.xsd">`
> >
> > `4. </xs:schema>`

---

> I get the custom selections, other than the 3 default selections.  Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that in the first scenario you've entered the `<` between the `<xs:schema>` and `</xs:schema>` tags, since for e.g.  would only be valid inside the document element content.

Since `xs` prefix is not bound to any namespace, or in general one namespace for which VS does not have the XSD, the Intellisense processor doesn't really know what to suggest beyond what's expected in any XML; hence, the 3 things you see.

When you type `<` above the `<xs:schema>`, the editor is not constrained by a context (as previously given by `<xs:schema>`), so VS goes through all the loaded XSDs for that document (`foo.xsd` being one of them) and gives you, in addition to the XML defaults, all the **global elements** found in `foo.xsd`; hence the more things you see.

I think that the confusion is increased by what seems to be a convenience the VS editor provides in that it associates the XML namespace URI with an actual XSD location. This is cool, but not standard. In the design of XML namespaces, there is no relationship between the value of an XML namespace URI and the XML Schema location which targets the same XML namespace. In other words, having declared a (default) XML namespace in the form of:

`xmlns="C:\Users\Win7Guru\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\foo.xsd"`

there is no standard specification which would instruct a processor to consistently look up a schema for that namespace, using the namespace value itself.

While many consider good practice to have a namespace URI as an URL that resolves to an actual resource on the Internet, many others would prefer the use of URNs as a better approach to avoid to some degree the confusion created here.

Comment: @Jon, you asked `why is this the case`, and I've explained it; as to what you're trying to do, it is not clear, nor did you ask help. Are you trying to edit an XML file as per foo.xsd? why would you type `xs:schema`? Please clarify and I'll help you.

Comment: I am trying have the intellisense work from within the <xs:schema> area.  If that isn't possible, I would like to know why it says cannot have multiple root elements.

Comment: To have Intellisense work, you first have to make sure that the `xs` alias is bound to a namespace that the XML editor in VS 2012 understands. If you want to know what the editor handles automatically or explicit, while editing your XML file, press F4. In the `Properties` tool window, click on the `Schemas` property (the ... on the right hand side). In the XML Schemas dialog box, look at the namespaces, or click `Add` to add something else. Make sure that the `Use` column has the checkboxes needed. Regardless of this, a wellformed XML document cannot have more than one root.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of the intellisense issue, you need to bind the namespace prefix `xs` to an appropriate namespace name.  So try adding

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

to the root element (`xs:schema`) of your document.  As Petru Gardea points out, this will have the effect of enabling intellisense only if the editor has some built-in knowledge of the namespace.  But even if it doesn't turn intellisense on, declaring the namespace is necessary if you want to have a conforming XSD schema document.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have to bind the namespace prefix to have a `well-formed XML document`.